# Jquery anchor#1.click change href of anchor#2 and click anchor#2

Tags: jquery

Here is the senario

I am using the CallTo: protocol to get the system to call a telephone number.
The user can change the number on the form, so the href needs to change to CallTo:xxxx

I would like to do the following:

1. when the CALL anchor is clicked it fires off a function (ok)
2. change a second anchor href to CallTo:xxxx (ok)
3. fire the click event on the second anchor (here's the problem)

For some reason the .click() event will not fire on the second link.

I am testing using the following code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#mobile").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#calling_clicker").prop("href", "http://www.google.co.uk").click();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="butt call-outbound" href="#" id="mobile">Call</a>

    <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk" id="calling_clicker">bbc</a>
</body>
```

Firebug is showing the link changing, but the click will just not fire.

Comment: $("#calling_clicker").prop("href","http://www.google.co.uk").trigger("click");

Comment: Just thought of that and it works, so cheers. But why doesn't .click() work?